# header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); stooped working when moved to a server

Tags: php

when running the code in xampp this statement works but when i moved the code to the production instance the code stops working.

ps: the way I'm evoking the php file is through a form submission.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
else
print "<br> referpage:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

when printing header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); it is returning empty.

Comment: And what do you expect? If empty - print empty value?

Comment: `REFERER` can be empty for several reasons, `https`, `.htaccess` rules like `RedirectMatch`, `restriction` of the `web browsers`, and many others, I suggest you don't trust on it... _'HTTP_REFERER'
    The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted_ [REFERER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location: $referer");
}
else
print "<br> referpage:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  is returning an empty string while it should hold a string value of a link to the previous page.

Comment: If the HTTP referer request header is not sent then the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is probably not set, although it could be an empty string. Whether it is set or not, in this case, could depend on the server.

Answer (score 0):

so i did session and it worked.

1) you need session_start(); at the top of every file
2) on the main pages add $_SESSION['location'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      this stores the current page address as a string
3) call header("Location: " . $_SESSION['location']); on demand.